# how to track of other application's memory and cpu usage by java coding

Tags: java

I want to show cpu and memory utilization of any application. For example memory and cpu utilization of notepad is shown in my java application dynamically like windows task manager.

How can i make it.Is it possible to make with out JNI or is there any api is available.

Answer (score 1):

For applications that are running as a Windows service or to collect Windows Performance statistics, you can use [NSClient4J](http://java.net/projects/nsclient4j).  It has very simple API.  Here is a link to a nice article on it: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2005/jw-0919-windowspm.html

If you want to collect statistics for any process (and on multiple platforms), check out [SIGAR](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar) API.  With a bit of custom code, you can do a lot with this library!